# Where to download opengl sdk (v. 3 or v. 4)?

Tags: c++, opengl

Wikipedia says that OpenGl V4.x is the latest. However my Visual Studio 2012 just offers the following version

```
#define GL_VERSION_1_1                    1
```

So my questions:

Which version is the most common that I should use? E.g. version 2.x because there are many tutorials, it is backward compatible etc.? I may have to mention that I normally prefer to write in C++, so is any version of Opengl e.g. offering namespaces? Are there huge differences between OpenGl 2,3 and 4?

**And where can I get the Libs+Header files e.g. for OpenGl 4?**

Comment: http://www.opengl.org/resources/

Comment: Microsoft doesn't like OpenGL (since they don't like any sane library and they like to invent generally crappy software), that's why you don't get a recent version of OpenGL with VS. About the differences between OpenGL 2, 3 and 4, from what I understood, versions 2 and 3 are rather hasty releases of OpenGL which would have actually made more sense as a beta release or something. I would definitely suggest OpenGL 4. While you're at it, switch to a unix-based operation system (i.e. anything but windows). You won't regret it!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> And where can I get the Libs+Header files e.g. for OpenGl 4?

You don't. OpenGL uses the so called "extension mechanism" to load functionality that's beyond the system ABI version. There exist third party libraries that do the extension loading and provide a header with the extended functionality.

Most popular is GLEW, which has its homepage at http://glew.sourceforge.net ; be warned though that right now of writing this GLEW is not up to date with OpenGL-3 and later core profiles. You must use compatibility profiles with GLEW or things get unstable.

Comment: So GLEW enables me to check whether my (or another) system supports special OpenGl 3/4 functions and allows me to use them? And e.g. http://sourceforge.net/projects/freeglut/ is offering additional functionalities like creating Windows? Is freeglut a good choice?

Comment: Regarding GLEW: Yes. Regarding FreeGLUT: It depends on your needs. GLUT has several shortcommings as an API and I'd not use it for serious projects. But it's good for simple techdemos and tryouts. But as soon as you start scratching your head, wondering "how the eff am I supposed to this this using that API?" it's time to move on. Notable exception: Using GLUT with Haskell, as Currying and functions being first class citizens nicely resolves all the issues.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, the most popular GL development library is GLEW:

http://glew.sourceforge.net

Comment: @datenwolf I didn't know how it's actually called. I just fell back to "library."

Answer (score 0):

There is no official OpenGL SDK. If you want to use newer functions you have to use a third party library such as GLEW or GLFW.

Comment: GLFW is not helpful in loading OpenGL functions.

Comment: @NicolBolas Please take a look at the chapter 7(OpenGL Extension Support) of the current GLFW user's guide : [http://www.glfw.org/GLFWUsersGuide277.pdf] . I agree that it's still good to use GLEW, but *not helpful* (at all) might be a bit of overstatement.